# How to make an IF statement work inside a KeyDown PrivateSub

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am programming a basic pong game in visual basic and need help with an if statement. When the ball hits an edge it resets to the middle of the screen, and "resetBall" gets set to true, which in turn should allow me to press "R" and make it move again.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox2.Bounds) Then
        direction = 1
    End If

    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds) Then
        direction = 0
    End If

    If direction = 0 Then
        PictureBox3.Left += 15
    End If

    If direction = 1 Then
        PictureBox3.Left -= 15
    End If

    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(leftBumper.Bounds) Then
        PictureBox3.SetBounds(325, 165, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X Or BoundsSpecified.Y)
        direction = 2
        resetBall0 = True
    End If

    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rightBumper.Bounds) Then
        PictureBox3.SetBounds(325, 165, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X Or BoundsSpecified.Y)
        direction = 2
        resetBall1 = True
    End If

End Sub
```

But when I use an "If" statement in the next part of the code, it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    Select Case e.KeyCode

        Case Keys.W
            PictureBox1.Top -= 8

        Case Keys.S
            PictureBox1.Top += 8

        Case Keys.Up
            PictureBox2.Top -= 8

        Case Keys.Down
            PictureBox2.Top += 8

            If resetBall1 = True Then
                Select Case e.KeyCode
                    Case Keys.R
                        direction = 1
                End Select
            End If

            If resetBall0 = True Then
                Select Case e.KeyCode
                    Case Keys.R
                        direction = 0
                End Select
            End If

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: `it doesn't work` isnt very helpful at all; it gives us nothing to go on.

Comment: When I press "R", it has literally no effect on anything, but there isn't an error message either.

Comment: Should the `Case Keys.Down` be `Case Keys.R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inside `Case Keys.Down` so Keycode will never be R...it's Down. Move your logic to its own case statement:

```
    Select Case e.KeyCode    
        Case Keys.W
            PictureBox1.Top -= 8

        Case Keys.S
            PictureBox1.Top += 8

        Case Keys.Up
            PictureBox2.Top -= 8

        Case Keys.Down
            PictureBox2.Top += 8

       Case Keys.R
            If resetBall1 = True Then
                direction = 1
            End If

            If resetBall0 = True Then
                direction = 0
            End If
    End Select
```